# Summation Formula Interpretation involving Roots of Unity

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

In a paper on Lacunary Recurrence Relations, D. H. Lehmer is beginning his preliminary information and presents the following sum formula:

Let $p,q,r,s$ be positive integers, and let $n,t$ be non-negative integers.  Define
$$\sigma_n=\sigma_n(p,q,r,s,t)=\sum_\eta(\eta_1\eta_2...\eta_{s-1})^t(1+\eta_1\epsilon+\eta_2\epsilon^2+...+\eta_{s-1}\epsilon^{s-1})^n$$
where $\epsilon=e^{2i\pi/pr}$ and each $\eta_r$ takes on the values $1,\eta,\eta^2,...,\eta^{pq-1}$ where $\eta=e^{2i\pi/pq}$, and the sum extends all over $(pq)^{s-1}$ possible combinations of these values.

This is really confusing to me.  I'm not really sure where to begin.  I think my biggest issue is seeing the $\eta_r$ but how do these $\eta_r$ "take on values" in the actual summation?  In other words, what exactly do I plug in for $\eta_1, \eta_2,...$?  I know there are $pq$ different values for these $\eta_r$ to take on, but I guess I'm just not sure how to employ the summation.  Even for small numbers trying some on my own I can't get off the ground and start.

EDIT:  I think I understand now how it works, but if someone could verify, that would be super.

Using smaller numbers helped me out.  So looking at $\sigma_2(1,2,3,3,2)$ as an example,

$\eta=e^{2i\pi/2}=e^{i\pi}=-1$

$\epsilon=e^{2i\pi/6}=e^{i\pi/3}$

Then we also have, since $pq-1=2-1=1$, my $\eta_r$ possbilities are just $1$ and $\eta$ itself.  Thus the $pq^{s-1}=2^2=4$ combinations are (as ordered pairs) $\{(1,1),(1,\eta),(\eta,1),(\eta,\eta)\}$.  Thus, there are 4 summands:
$$(1\cdot 1)^3(1+1\cdot\epsilon+1\cdot\epsilon^2)^3+(1\cdot\eta)^3(1+1\cdot\epsilon+\eta\cdot\epsilon^2)^3$$
$$+(\eta\cdot 1)^3(1+\eta\cdot\epsilon+1\cdot\epsilon^2)^3+(\eta\cdot\eta)^3(1+\eta\epsilon+\eta\cdot\epsilon^2)^3$$

Is this correctt?